# Bug in String.split('.')?

Tags: apex, string

I can hardly believe it but `split()` doesn't work on the `.` character:

```
String createDate = '01.2.2013';
String[] cd = createDate.split('.');
System.assertEquals(3, cd.size());   // Boom!
```

Tried with `'\.'` but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The separator string used in the split method is a regular expression and "." is a special character in regular expressions.

The regular expression for a literal "." is "\."

However "\" is also used to [escape characters when expressing Strings in Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm), and so this character too needs escaping:

```
String[] cd = createDate.split('\\.');
```

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#SplittingStringsExample) provides an interesting example, if you need to use "\" as the separator:

```
List<String> parts = filename.split('\\\\');
```

Comment: Well that's logical...for a given value of "logical". Ta!

Comment: This answer now blogged: http://wp.me/p2XgT8-4U

Comment: Is there any method like c# Getfilename() in apex?